# Count same products inside a order

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using m-m relationship between orders and products.

```
Product_Order:
ProductId
OrderId
```

I'm having hard time to correct this line below:

```
ProductAmount = db.Orders.Where(o=> o.Id == id).Sum(o => o.Products.Count(p=> p.Id == x.Id))
```

I'm trying to read current `Order` and to get the amount of same `Product` inside that order.

```
public ActionResult GetOrder(Guid id) {

     var currentOrder = db.Orders.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

     var returnOrder = new {

         FirstName = currentOrder.User.FirstName,
         LastName = currentOrder.User.LastName,
         Address = currentOrder.User.Address,              
         TotalPrice = currentOrder.TotalPrice,
         OrderDate = currentOrder.OrderDate,
         Products = currentOrder.Products.Select(x => new {

             ProductName = x.ProductName, 
             ProductAmount = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == id).Sum(o => o.Products.Count(p => p.Id == x.Id))

         })
     };                 

     return Json(returnOrder);
 }
```

I would appreciate if you could correct the `ProductAmount` line.

--- Additional code:

```
  $.post("/Home/GetOrder", { "id": orderId },
                function (data) {
                    if (data) {

                        $.each(data.Products, function(index, item) {
                            Alert(item.ProductAmount); 
                        });
```

Comment: Use a `.Groupby()` to group by the `ProductName` and the `.Count()` the result of each grouping - e.g. `Products = currentOrder.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductName).Select(y => new { ProductName = y.Key, ProductAmount = y.Count() })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get `[object Object],[object Object]` when I read it as 'data.ProductAmount' in View.  How should I read it correctly?

Comment: Show your script (I cannot guess what your code is)

Comment: It might be worth also posting expected input/output

Comment: @StephenMuecke It's added now.

Comment: If you have used the code in my previous comment it will alert a number (the number of products)

Comment: @StephenMuecke `ProductAmount = currentOrder.Products.GroupBy(c => c.ProductName).Select(y => new { ProductName = y.Key, ProductAmount = y.Count() })` this is the code I'm using now. I had to change `x` to `c` because `x` was already used.

Comment: Not in the code that you showed its not :) But that has nothing to do with your claim that your get `[object Object],[object Object]` which will not be the case using that code

Comment: @StephenMuecke My bad! I used your code at `ProductAmount` instead `Products` itself. But now I just get the value `1` when there is actually `9` of same products in that order. I just get `1` all the time no matter what.

Comment: If you have 9 `Products` with `ProductName = "ABC"` then it WILL return `ProductAmount = 9` (I cannot see your data!)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hmm I have 9 `Products` with `ProductName = "ABC"` in `currentOrder` but I get the value `1`.

Comment: Then you have not used the code I showed you.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am using your code: `Products = currentOrder.Products.GroupBy(x => x.ProductName).Select(y => new { ProductName = y.Key, ProductAmount = y.Count() })`.

Comment: Then you do **NOT** have more than one `Product` with the same `ProductName` And if you tell me that `1 + 1 = 3`, I wont believe you either. I cannot see you data so there is no point continuing with this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Correct. Something went wrong adding multiple of same products into a `Order`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I created a list of products before adding it into `Order.Products`. I debugged it to make sure products-list had the right amount. It was, but in my db, there's only one row of same `Order.Id` and `Product.Id`. Meaning only one product were added. Is this because database can't have more than one unique row? Both `Product.Id` and `Order.Id` are `FK` references.

Comment: If you have a new question, then ask a new question and provide all the relevant details

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, will do :) Thanks for the answer for this question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Since I no longer need `Count` as  `currentOrder.Product_Order` already contain `Quantity` value, how do I set both `Name` and `Amount/Quantity` in similar way? I can make a new question if you prefer that.

Comment: You need to ask a new question :) (what your asking has nothing to do with  this question)